# How to show small tab interfaces in ordinary activities (non-tabactivity)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I wish to show tabs in an activity such that one of the tabs will be a comment form and the other tab will be a list of comments submitted by other users of the application.

I do not wish to implement it as a TabActivity - where the whole screen is occupied by the view, with the tabs at the top. I wish to show this tab interface below a image both of which will be in a <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a layout to TabActivity where you have LinearLayout on the top as you desired and then the tabs